# Create multiple dataframes by subsetting one dataframe based on the condition of another dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose I have dataframe df1

```
 Home.ID Timeframe_Start Timeframe_End
2     58960      1476748800    1477353600
4     56862      1474329600    1474934400
6     40482      1454284800    1454889600
8     52105      1476748800    1477353600
10    37244      1476748800    1477353600
12    58213      1476748800    1477353600
14    17734      1458000000    1458604800
16    39786      1458000000    1458604800
18    42613      1458000000    1458604800
```

Then I have a second dataframe df2 that includes the same home_ids, but has  many different instances of it (here is only a part of it displayed)

```
home_id             property_name timestamp_millis      value
1        58960        inside_temperature     1.475849e+12  18.510000
2        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.810000
3        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.630000
4        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.470000
5        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.300000
6        58960        inside_temperature     1.475851e+12  19.470000
2482     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476755e+12  55.000000
2483     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476755e+12  53.000000
2484     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476755e+12  51.000000
2485     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476755e+12  47.000000
2486     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476755e+12  46.000000
2487     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476756e+12  55.000000
2488     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476756e+12  58.000000
2489     58960 boiler_output_temperature     1.476756e+12  61.000000
```

Now I would like to create for every row of df1 another dataframe with all the instances of df2 that have the same ID and fulfill the condition property name= 'inside_temperature' and their timestamp is within df1 columns timeframe start and timeframe end.

So as results, I have created 18 differet dataframes; one for each instance in df1 - which only include 'inside temperature' and timestamp values defined in df1.

```
 home_id             property_name timestamp_millis      value
    1        58960        inside_temperature     1.475849e+12  18.510000
    2        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.810000
    3        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.630000
    4        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.470000
    5        58960        inside_temperature     1.475850e+12  19.300000
    6        58960        inside_temperature     1.475851e+12  19.470000
```

Comment: We need some effort from your side. please share the code that you tried so far.

Comment: I tried **for(i in df1) {
    nam <- paste("control", df1$Home.ID, "it", sep = ".")
    assign(nam, subset(df2,  df2$home_id== df1$Home.ID & df2$property_name== "inside_temperature"& df2$timestamp_millis >= df1$Timeframe_Start & df2$timestamp_millis <= df1$Timeframe_End)}** but that gave me the error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your dataframes to reproduce the code, I'd just give a general suggestion to avoid for-loops and get all your data in one place.

You can use tidyr and purrr packages.

for example:

```
# group by Home.ID and nest

df1 <- df1 %>% 
            group_by(Home.ID) %>% 
            nest()
```

Then write a function that takes Home.ID and the rest of the data, apply the conditions you want to filter df2 and give you a df with the desired rows.

```
GetDetails <- function(id,data) {
    # add your conditions to filter df2 
    df2 %>% filter(home_id==id &
                   property_name== 'inside_temperature' &
                   timestamp_millis> data$Timeframe_Start &
                   timestamp_millis< data$Timeframe_End
    )
}
```

Then add a column to df that hold lists, each list has the resulting df from the previous step

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
        mutate(All_Data=map2(Home.ID,data,GetDetails))
```

It might need some modifications, but generally sth like this would work and give you a df with 18 rows holding all the info.